# jQuery dataTable to show recent records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm new to dataTables concept in jQuery. I'm trying my best to learn and work with dataTables. My requirement is to show most recent recent records when the checkbox is checked. I'm using jQuery datatable.

Below is my sample code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initTable();
        } );

    function initTable(){
            oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
                                "aaSorting": [[ 12, "desc" ]],
                                "oLanguage": {
                                "sProcessing": "<span style='font-size:20px; color:blue;'>Loading...<span/>",
                                 "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select>'+
                                   '<option value="10">10</option>'+ 
                                   '<option value="20">20</option>'+
                                   '<option value="30">30</option>'+
                                   '<option value="40">40</option>'+
                                   '<option value="50">50</option>'+
                                   '</select> records'
                                            },
                                "bProcessing": true,
                                "bServerSide": true,
                                "asStripeClasses": [ 'evenrow', 'oddrow' ],
                                "sAjaxSource": "spreadData.do?method=searchSpreadData",
                                 "fnServerParams": function ( aoData )
                                 { 
                                   aoData.push({"name":"searchCriteria.toDate", "value": $('#todateId').attr("value") });
                                   aoData.push( { "name":"searchCriteria.SerialNumber", "value":$('#serialNumberId').attr("value")});
                                   aoData.push( { "name":"searchCriteria.formatId", "value": $('#formatId').attr("value")});
                                   aoData.push( {  "name":"searchCriteria.fromDate", "value": $('#fromdateId').attr("value")});
                                   aoData.push( {  "name":"searchCriteria.doSearch", "value": $('#doSearchId').attr("value")});   
                                   aoData.push( {  "name":"searchCriteria.spreadpercentage", "value": $('#spreadPercentage').attr("value")}); 
                             },
                                 "aoColumnDefs": [
                                     { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                                                               { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 11 ] }
                                    ],
                                "bJQueryUI": true,
                                "bFilter": false
                        });
            $('#displayRecentRecords').click( function() {
                alert("step1");
                oTable.fnDraw();
        } );
    }   
  //The below function is not getting called when checkbox is checked from UI.   
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            alert("step2");
             if($("#displayRecentRecords").is(':checked')){
               return true;
           }
            return !aData[11];

         }
    );

Show Recent Records:<input type="checkbox" id="displayRecentRecords"/>
```

Please see my sample code above. When I run the application and select the checkbox **step1** alertbox is shown but **step2** alert box is not getting called.

**Please suggest what are the changes to be done to the above code to call last mentioned datatable function (alertbox which prints step2).**

I'm new to dataTable concepts in jQuery. I read the documentation and came across few examples. Please find the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9jf2k53p/135/.

Please suggest what modifications to be done in JSFiddle to show the most recent records when the checkbox is checked.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you define "most recent records"?

Comment: @jonmrich - When user checks the checkbox , it has to show most recent date records only. I already have that logic implemented at server side but issue is as said, last mentioned jquery function is not getting called when i click the checkbox (which is printing step2 in alertbox). Thanks.

Comment: Did you test my code from my answer?

Comment: @jonmrich , not yet tested..my bad server went down..i will test and let u know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
```

to this:

```
$oTable.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
```

OR (not sure which will work in your case):

```
$oTable.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
```

You need to define the table as part of this function. That's what the `oTable` is for, as you defined this variable on the 6th line of your code above.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to define custom filtering function before initializing the table.

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
   function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ){
      // ... skipped ...
   }
);

var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cv3kg1gv/1/) for code and demonstration.